# spring batch rollback all steps in case of exception in one the the steps

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
Job lensJob(JobBuilderFactory jbf, StepBuilderFactory sbf) throws Exception{

    return jbf
            .get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobResultListener)
                .start(step1Lens())
                .next(step2Lens())
                .build();

}
```

so in my case my job contains 2 steps that reads from the same file and insert in different table of database ,what i'm looking for is a way to rollback automatically all the steps when an exception is thrown and in case some records are inserted to be removed automatically

Comment: You cannot. Each steps (or even parts of the step) are persisted and committed in the database. You cannot rollback committed items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible, there is no inter-step transactions.

> reads from the same file and insert in different table

You can have two writers (one writer for each table) configured as delegates in a `CompositeItemWriter`. With this configuration, a transaction rollback will rollback items written in both tables.

Hope this helps.